# How can i hide the url of image when i post image on the Facebook by fbconnect?

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios5

I am using this code for post the image on the facebook but it also shows image url on the facebook. I want to hide this url:

this is my code for posting an image to facebook

```
#pragma mark Facebook 

-(void)facebook
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"I'm using Shape App", @"message",  @"I'm using Shape App", @"caption",
        @"http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/3kft472rvl2qtnzx11_Sample.png", @"picture",
        @"I'm using Shape App", @"title",nil];
    [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
  }
```

please check the image below

[image]

Comment: have you tried including the image data itself in the `source` parameter instead of including a URL to it in `picture`?

Comment: yes i have tried this one also but it is working in my code

Comment: what is image1? is it `NSData`? did you try with `file` as a parameter name?

Comment: i have tried source as data or image both

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is posting a URL, so it shows up as that: A *link* you shared. It does not matter that this link does point to an image and not a website.

Your options to change that are,

a) post a link to an Open Graph page instead, that contains the image – then you can set a title and description that will show up for that shared link, or

b) post it as a real photo, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved by latest ios6 facebook integration:
for this you have to import Social.framework after this put this code in method where you want to call Facebook.but it will work only in iOS 6 and later

```
       NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/3kft472rvl2qtnzx11_Sample.png"]];
 if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])

   {
    mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I am using Shape App"]];
    [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
   }

  else

   {
    UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Account" message:@"There are no Facebook accounts configured.You can add or create a Facebook account in Settings" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];
}
[mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result)
 {
   // NSLog(@"dfsdf");

    switch (result) {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:

            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}];
```